# Sort list of dates and sort other list based on this sorting order in R

Tags: r

I've got a list of dates which are not in the correct order: "1-12-2019"  "17-11-2019" "18-11-2019"

Besides this list of dates, I've also got a list of corresponding values: 2 3 2

I want to sort the dates list in the ascending order. And in the same order that the dates list is sorted, I want to sort the values list.

For example:

Current situation:

- datesLst: "1-12-2019"  "17-11-2019" "18-11-2019"
- valuesLst: 2 3 2

Wanted situation:

- datesLst: "17-11-2019" "18-11-2019" "1-12-2019"
- valuesLst: 3 2 2

Would appreciate it if I could get some help.

Comment: Please share a reproducible example. Is it a data frame? Or an actual list?

Comment: It is an actual list/vector, not a dataframe.
datesLst <- c("17-11-2019", "18-11-2019", "1-12-2019")

Comment: list and vectors are two different objects though. What you described is a vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to order your dates and use them as index to order the values, i.e.

```
i1 <- order(as.Date(datesLst, format = '%d-%m-%Y'))
datesLst[i1]
#[1] "17-11-2019" "18-11-2019" "1-12-2019" 
valueslist[i1]
#[1] 3 2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the following code

```
res <- as.numeric(names(sort(setNames(as.Date(s, format = '%d-%m-%Y'),c(2,3,2)))))
```

such that

```
> res
[1] 3 2 2
```

**DATA**

```
s <- c("17-11-2019", "18-11-2019", "1-12-2019")
```